# Charge Macbook pro M1 with Dell 65 W Charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

I forgot my Macbook pro M1 charger and I am traveling for 2 months. I have my work laptop Dell Latitude 7420 which has type c charger of 65 Watt.

```
Output: 
5.0V = 3.0A/15.0W
9.0V = 3.0A/27.0W
15.0V = 3.0A/45.0W
20.0V = 3.0A/65.0W
```

Answer (score 2):

As soon as the plug is USB-C, it is compatible. There is no voltage concern, it is a standard.

The only concern is the power (in Watts), but is not so important.

- If the power of the charger is bigger than the one needed by the computer, no problem.
- If the computer, on the contrary, needs more power than the charger is able to deliver, then the only concern is that the computer will charge slower - and maybe even slower than the power is drained if the computer is used in the same time. In this case, you will need time where the computer charges without being used.
  Also, the charger may become hotter (and thus wear out quicker) as it is always used at full capacity. So in this case, do not use on a regular basis, just as a spare solution.

Conclusion : no problem, use it.

Comment: According to MacTracker, the MacBook Pro M1 (13" '20) specifies "61W USB-C Power Adapter" The MPB M1 (14", '21) specifies a "67W or 96W USB-C Power Adapter" The MBP M1 (16" '21_ specifies a  "140W USB-C Power Adapter". The larger wattages specified for the 14" and 16" screens are a combination of powering the increased core processor options, and the larger screens.